# Reading params from custom resource as json in lambda gives json decode error

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

Trying to Read parameters of custom resource in AWS passed to a lambda. Trying to parse these parameter as json this gives me json decode error.

I am extracting them via handlers event attribute. Can you please suggest what's wrong here ?

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow!  It's difficult (read: impossible) to answer your question without seeing your actual code.  Please read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) on how to reframe your question.

Comment: Please edit your question to show us the code you are using, and the data that is being passed back from the Custom Resource.

Comment: Sure I will put more details . But the answer below helps . I was assuming dict as json

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Usually the Event is of Type Dict, to make it JSON replace the single quotes to double quotes and change dict to string.

Detailed info:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/python-handler.html